# Creating multiple ZIPs from multiple directories using Gradle dynamically

Tags: gradle, build, zip

I have a relatively complex directory structure in my build, from which I would like to create multiple ZIP files. The structure is like this:

```
+ project root
    + -- build.gradle
    + -- + foo
         + -- bar-1
         |   + -- bar-1.a.json
         |   + -- bar-1.a.xml
         |   + -- bar-1.b.json
         |   + -- bar-1.b.xml
         |
         + -- bar-2
         |   + -- bar-2.a.json
         |   + -- bar-2.a.xml
         |   + -- bar-2.b.json
         |   + -- bar-2.b.xml
         |
         + ...
         + -- bar-n
             + -- bar-n.a.json
             + -- bar-n.a.xml
             + -- bar-n.b.json
             + -- bar-n.b.xml
```

From this structure, I would like to create ZIP files for each `bar-x` directory, e.g. from `foo/bar-1` directory, a ZIP file should be created in `out/foo/bar-1.zip`, from `foo/bar-2` a ZIP file should be created in `out/foo/bar-2.zip`  and so on

It is important, that new directories might appear later on, so I **cannot hard-code the names**, Gradle should list the directories in `foo` on each build.

Can someone give me a sample on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following should do:

```
task zipAll
file('foo').eachDirMatch(~/bar-.*/) { barDir ->
    def taskName = "zip${barDir.name.capitalize()}"
    task "$taskName"(type: Zip) {
        from barDir
        destinationDir file('out/foo/')
        baseName barDir.name
    }
    zipAll.dependsOn taskName
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you very much. Adding a task dynamically is really a neat solution to this.  :)